# Android BitmapFactory.decodeStream can't decode some URL's

Tags: android, bitmap, stream

I have one weird problem and I'm trying to solve it a couple of hours already. Problem is that this code below can decode all images except those one which have small first letter in name. For example, it's working for Dog.png or 123.png but it doesn't work for dog.png, cat.png or any other with small first letter. It just displays some random color for them. I'm confused. Any ideas?

```
    Bitmap bitmap = null;

    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    try {
        bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imagePath).getContent(), null, options);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    image.setImageBitmap(bimage);
```

Comment: Your code can't compile - image.setImageBitmap(bimage); = typo. please copy&paste your real code.

Comment: comment #2: split "new URL(imagePath).getContent()", test if you got null. paste stack trace.. (help us help you)

Comment: It's the real code. I added the last line by hand after copy/paste of that top code so I mistyped it. I tested new URL(imagePath).getContent() and it doesn't return null. This is really strange problem. It shouldn't be important if the first letter is uppercase or lowercase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. Pictures from those URL's can be decoded but the problem was it was too big so it showed extremely enlarged and looked like it's not showing.

First we need to catch description of image like this:

```
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent(), null, options);
```

Then scale it to desired width/height, reqHeight/reqWidth are wanted size parameters:

```
int height = options.outHeight;
int width = options.outWidth;
int inSampleSize;

if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {
if (width > height) {
inSampleSize = Math.round((float)height / (float)reqHeight);
} 
else {
inSampleSize = Math.round((float)width / (float)reqWidth);
}
}
```

After that just repeat that code from question:

```
Bitmap bitmap = null;

options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
try {
    bitmap =  BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(imagePath).getContent(), null, options);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Now we can save it to some directory:

```
File file = new File(some_path\image.png);

    if (!file.exists() || file.length() == 0) {
            file.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            fos.flush();
```

Image in now saved and we can grab it and display in our ImageView called image:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(some_path\image.png);
image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: So I could set `options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize`.